# How do I extract an attribute/property in Perl using XML::Twig module?

Tags: perl, xml-twig

If I have the below sample XML, how do I extract the `_Id` from the field using `XML::Twig`?

```xml
<note>
    <to _Id="100">Share</to>
    <from>Jane</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>A simple text</body>
</note>
```

I've tried combinations of the below with no luck.

```
sub getId {
    my ($twig, $mod) = @_;

    ##my $to_id = $mod->field('to')->{'_Id'};  ## does not work
    ##my $to_id = $mod->{'atts'}->{_Id};       ## does not work
    ##my $to_id = $mod->id;                    ## does not work

    $twig->purge;
}
```

Comment: have you tried `$mod->att('_Id')` (assuming $mod is the node `<to>`)?

Comment: @ialarmedalien i tried that as well and no luck i call this sub when i see the node "note" `my $twig = new XML::Twig(
                          TwigHandlers => { note  => \&getId }
                        );`

Comment: `_Id` is not an attribute of `note`, so you won't find it there! You need to do `my $to= $note->first_child( 'to'); my $to_id= $to->att( '_Id');`. You can't get the attribute using `$to->id` unless you declare the id to be `_Id` (using the `id` option when you create the twig). Also `$to->field` returns the text of a sub element of `to`, not an element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one way to get `100`.  It uses the `first_child` method:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Twig;

my $xml = <<XML;
<note>
    <to _Id="100">Share</to>
    <from>Jane</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>A simple text</body>
</note>
XML

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(twig_handlers => { note => \&getId });
$twig->parse($xml);

sub getId {
    my ($twig, $mod) = @_;
    my $to_id = $mod->first_child('to')->att('_Id');
    print "$to_id \n";
}
```